# Create a categorical variable for time containing categories

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, analysis

I have a time column but I want to create a column 'Part of the Day'
Creating a categorical variable for time containing the categories
Midnight : (23:00 - 02:00)
Early Morning : (03:00 - 06:00)
Morning : (07:00 - 10:00)
Noon : (11:00 - 14:00)
Evening : (15:00 - 18:00)
Night : (19:00 - 22:00)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way :

Let's say that you have a pandas DataFrame containing a column date : `df.date`. I'm not sure what's the format of your column but you should transform it to a numeric format.

Let's say that you have the same format as you mentioned `19:00`, then you can transform it to numeric by doing :

`df['date_numeric'] = df.date.apply(lambda date: int(date[:2]))`

What you can do then is to create multiple condition using `.apply()` function to create a new column `category` :

`df['category'] = df.date_numeric.apply(lambda date: "Early Morning" if 3 <= date <= 6 else "Morning" if 7 <= date <= 10 else ... else "Midnight")`

As the "Midnight" case is trickier you should treat all other cases in the `if` conditions and put "Midnight" as the last `else` condition.

Comment: Thats very helpful. My Time Column is in this "2021-04-15 11:00:00". I am trying to extract the time from it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that proper DateTime format or a String ? If it's a String, you should use the following command to turn it into a datetime format `df.date = pandas.to_datetime(df.date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` .

Then you could use the following command (replace `date` by `date.hour`) 

`df['category'] = df.date.apply(lambda date: "Early Morning" if 3 <= date.hour <= 6 else "Morning" if 7 <= date.hour <= 10 else ... else "Midnight")`